# Blockchain Node

Tags: blockchain, txpool

I am looking for some answers on what information is considered on-node? If I setup a full node, will I get all the details (internal transactions, smart contracts, mempool) from that node. I might not even be asking the right question here but will try.

Answer (score 0):

An full node has every data on the blockchain, transactions, blocks. Some intermediate states may be missing although they can be reconstructed from existing data.

An archive node has access to every data on the blockchain, transactions, internal transactions, intermediate states, etc.

A node only has access to the current mempool, even in that case some transactions aren't published to the mempool but mined directly.

The contracts' source code isn't available.